# Error while Generating Signed APK in android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location 'E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19-1' (Expected 'E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19')
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_gdk-google-19' in inconsistent location 'E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_gdk-google-19-1' (Expected 'E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_gdk-google-19')
Observed package id 'build-tools;20.0.0' in inconsistent location 'E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W' (Expected 'E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0')
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:mergeReleaseShaders
:app:compileReleaseShaders
:app:generateReleaseAssets
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:prePackageMarkerForRelease
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Comment: Check your dependencies, you get google ads dependency from two places

Comment: Please try solutions here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199518